# Muting / Unmuting HTML5 Audio with jQuery

Tags: jquery, mobile-safari, html5-audio

I am making custom controls to "play" and "mute / unmute" an HTML5 audio element.

The following code works as expected in Chrome:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var audioPlayer;

function init(){
    audioPlayer = $('audio')[0];
}

function startPlaying(){
    $('button#play').hide();
    audioPlayer.play();
}

function toggleMute(){
    if(audioPlayer.muted == false){ 
        audioPlayer.muted = true;
        $('button#mute').addClass('muted');
    }
    else{ 
        audioPlayer.muted = false;
        $('button#mute').removeClass('muted');
    }
}

init();
$('button#play').on('click', startPlaying );
$('button#mute').on('click', toggleMute );
```

});

However, in mobile Safari (iOS 5), the first tap on the "mute" button will successfully run at least the line

```
$('button#mute').addClass('muted');
```

, which updates the icon image, but it doesn't actually mute the audio. Subsequent taps on the "mute" button do nothing (don't mute / unmute the audio or seem to change the class).

How can I get this mute/unmute toggle to work in mobile Safari?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrengy/wCXGv/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"on iOS devices, the audio level is always under the user’s physical control. The volume property is not settable in JavaScript. Reading the volume property always returns 1."

Looks like you have to use the hardware switch. It seems that on an iPhone the volume switch will not affect Safaris volume(defaults to the ringer volume, unless a sound a sound is playing then you can adjust Safaris volume), whereas, on the iPod, the volume switch does.
"

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video.pdf